# Get array number by position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Array in php each record goes inside a hidden div

```
    $array=(15,20,50,23,10);
    
    record list (loop)
    <div>15</div> position 1
    <div>20</div> position 2
    <div>50</div> position 3
    <div>23</div> position 4
    <div>10</div> position 5
```

The code is

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) { 

<input id="postid" name="postid" type="hidden" value="$array[$i]; ?>"

}
```

If I click div post id (position 2) I get 20 if I click div post id position 3 I get 50

```
(function ($){
$(document).on('click','#postid',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var postid=$('#postid').val();
console.log(postid);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you realise that Ids are supposed to be unique?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking

Comment: When I click I get the last id from the array but I need to do it according to the click position

Comment: I can guess what you want, but you still haven't made it clear.  Please edit your question and make it clear.  Explicitly clear.  Otherwise, it may get flagged for deletion.

Comment: Do not use id for this kinda logic. As @RohitGupta said they are supposed to be unique. It is better to use some class or attribute.

Comment: just replace $('#postid').val() by $(this).text() what ever the css selector you are using

Answer (score 0):

So you need to *echo* the input tag along with the `Position` text. Also, it is a good practice to wrap the text node inside a parent tag for referring, like a `div`. `id` needs to be unique for each HTML element. In your case, having an `id` or `class` attribute is trivial anyways since the input type is `hidden`.

So, better to add a class for the parent `div` tag and output the `text` on it's click listener.

**Backend Snippet:**

```
<?php

$array = array(15,20,50,23,10);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    echo "<div class='post'><input name='postid_$array[$i]' type='hidden' value='$array[$i]' /> Position ".($i + 1)."</div>";
}
```

**Frontend Snippet:**

```
(function ($){
    $(document).on('click','.post',function(e){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[**Online Output UI demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0wy3sudc/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

**PHP snippet**

```php
$array = array(15,20,50,23,10);
$i = 1;

foreach($array as $single_value) {
  echo "<div class='post'><input name='postid_".$i."' type='hidden' value='".$single_value."' /> Position ".$i."</div>";
  $i++;
}
```

**Front-end Javascript**

```
(function ($){
  $(document).on('click','.post',function(e){
    console.log($(this).find('input').val());
  });
})(jQuery);
```